# Is it possible to use .NetCore libraries in a .Net Standard application?

Tags: .net-core, blazor, webassembly, .net-standard, opensilver

We've started to look at the newly announced OpenSilver (open source SilverLight) which runs in WebAssembly as a possible solution for our cross platform needs.

OpenSilver is built using .Net Standard 2.0.
We have existing code which is built using the .NetCore libraries.

From what I've read, it looks like .NetCore sits on top of/uses .Net Standard (BCL Libraries).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/september/net-standard-demystifying-net-core-and-net-standard

How do I go include/use my existing .NetCore libraries into the new Visual Studio app/project?
Is this even possible (Without splitting into a client/server approach)?

Thanks

Comment: What is open source SilverLight ? Do you really mean that Microsoft revealed SilverLight's source, especially the rendering engine ?

Comment: enet: New open source release announced a couple of days ago.: https://www.opensilver.net/announcements/introducing-opensilver.aspx

Comment: I think your question should be: "Is it possible to use .Net Standard libraries in a .Net Core application?" Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Alexan: That one does make sense. However with OpenSilver I think the paradigm is a little different in that the app would be built using the new OpenSilver extensions which are built in VS with .Net Standard. Thoughts?

Comment: .NET Standard can be only library, not application, because it isn't platform but specification

Comment: Your .net core libs are also .net standard (.2x mostly). Blazor can run most of these. For what I understand here OpenSilver uses the same approach: load normal .net DLLs and interpret them with Mono. So I would say: It will probably work. Give it a try.

Comment: Henk Holteman: I tried creating a sample OpenSilver and just dropping a .NetCore library in and get the following error "FooLib is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). FooLib supports: netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0)". Am I attempting to add libraries incorrectly?

Comment: @JohnB, I'm not excited any more. I thought Microsoft has released the source code of Silverlight to the open source community. It seems to me that the only difference between Blazor and Opensilverlight that the last uses xaml. But, hey, I'm interested in the rendering engine of silverlight. I do hope that one day our beloved Silverlight is resurrected

Comment: @enet, for us this could have huge upside as we search for cross platform UI that will work with .NetCore. It's in alpha-ish stage, and they are seem to be aggressive in what they're trying to achieve. We'll see how ti plays out.

Comment: you can look at [UNO](https://platform.uno/) which use XAML for Webassembly

Comment: I haven't used blazor much at all, but in my brief testing with OpenSilver I found I was able to use NetStandard libraries such as ReactiveUI and so forth. So the sell here is it brings that WPF / Xamarin Forms style development back to the web.